# Commit failed from eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I try to use Eclipse SVN plugin.

`update` action works correctly but when I execute commit I see following:

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E200007: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E200007: CHECKOUT can only be performed on a version resource [at this time].
svn: E175002: CHECKOUT request failed on '/dent-001/!svn/rvr/5126/#PATH_TO_CLASS#
```

It is executes normally if I use tortoise SVN.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

From your trace I think you are making commit on class file that is not in the repo. Don't select class files for commit and put your output class folder out of the sources. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This class exist in repository!!!

Comment: just now I commit it using tortoise svn

Comment: Even so - don't put class files in svn, it's meant for source and packed files (jar, zip etc). Your class could be compiled later.

Comment: I am about .java class

Comment: If it's .java then this is fail of the plugin. Since you put it in the repo from tortoise, just refresh your project and download it again. Sometimes the eclipse plugin doesn't work very well (I'm tired of using it). But in the trace looks like .class file, not .java.